# Is make suitable for picking what functions to include

Tags: c, makefile

I have a set of functions foo1(), foo2(), foo3(), ... in my foo.c file.
Ideally I would like to choose freely which functions will be included into the programm and which ones will be ignored / commented out.
Is the makefile suitable for such a task?

Feel free to tell me if there is a better / more convenient way to achieve this.

Comment: Why you can't you leave them all in?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve by doing this?

Comment: `I would like to choose freely which functions will be included into the programm and which ones will be ignored`..that's why you call them, right?

Comment: Also, don't ya trust your compiler? Why?

Comment: Hello [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: How about using [pre-processor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_preprocessors.htm)? You can declare these flags in make file.

Comment: "Ain't got no time to lose 0.002s of preprocessing my 3 functions that I don't use"... Yet you coded them for way more time, why not just commenting them ??

Comment: Use definitions and include/exclude parts of program with `#ifdef`. Then `make` can be called with different profile (definition set).

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe you need some marcos and -D option?

```
#ifdef FOO1
void foo1()
{}
#endif
#ifdef FOO2
void foo2()
{}
#endif
```

then ,in makefile add flage -DFOO2 ,then only foo2 will be compiled and foo1 will be ignored.
for example:

```
gcc -DFOO2 main.c
```

Comment: I like this a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way is to leave them where they are and just not call the ones to be ignored. Some compilers may optimize and exclude that code from binary.

The second most convenient way is to use preprocessor `#ifdef` directives and compiler `-D` flag.

The least convenient way is to write a script which will build `foo.c` with only the functions requested and call that script from `make`.

Comment: Very informative. If I want to be sure about what functions get into the binary I stick to the preprocessor directives. Thank you!